# iOS10 - Disable pushs on the client side

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, ios10

Today I found a really odd issue with iOS10.

In the past code I could disable pushs on the client side (to be sure when a user logouts, for instance). With iOS10 if I call `unregisterRemoteNotifications` after that the `registerForRemoteNotifications` does nothing. The `isRegisteredForRemoteNotification` is always NO. I have tried to use the [new notifications API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37967012/684803) but it didn't help.

There are more [people](https://github.com/lionheart/openradar-mirror/issues/15952) with the [same problem](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/64377) and [some solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38992133/684803) aren't helpful. Has anyone found a work around to this?